# I have a series 14 Sasquatch (Square Foot) missing facial paint, is it normal?

Tags: minifigures

Hi I have the [camera holding Sasquatch](http://brickset.com/sets/71010-15/Square-Foot) but he does not have the black eyebrows and muzzle. The eyes and teeth are there but the rest is just brown.

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not normal. It would usually look exactly like it is on the lego website. I suggest you call the lego customer service.